# VirtualBox - Android x86 - Don't boot in GUI but just in command line

Tags: boot, virtualbox, android-x86

I followed a lot of different tutorials to install Android_x86 on VirtualBox (actually I want to install Android on a virtual machine, so if you have alternatives, I'm interested), I followed its step by step, but when the installation is completed : the GUI won't start... I just get this:
[image: boot]

I find a solution [here](https://android-x86.narkive.com/k25hBHK2/help-android-x86-4-2-can-t-boot-into-gui-just-command-line) to edit the GRUB boot parameters. But the config I have doesn't match with theirs...

[Here](http://techanji.blogspot.com/2013/04/android-wont-boot-into-gui-only-command.html) I have to change `androidboot.hardware=android_x86` to `androidboot.hardware=x86` but on my config I have `androidboot.selinux=permissive`

The ISO I downloaded is `android-x86_64-8.1-r1.iso` from [here](http://www.android-x86.org/download) and the version of VirtualBox is `6.0.2 r128162 (Qt5.6.3)`

If anybody can help me, thank in advance ! :D

Comment: I'm trying to run Android x86 in VMWare, with the same issue. Boots to console, no idea how to start the android UI!

Comment: See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1512632/dont-boot-in-android-gui-just-in-command-line/).

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Settings -> Display -> graphic controller set to -> VBoxVGA.  Turn off Enable 3D Acceleration. This worked for me in my VM.

Comment: didn't work for me with Android-x86 6.0 Marshmallow (R3)

Comment: This worked with Android 9 (k49) and VirtualBox 6.1.10 on Ubuntu 20.04. The 3D Acceleration checkbox is off by default. All I had to do is go into the machine settings under the display tab and set the graphics controller to "VBoxVGA".

Comment: Worked for me with 1.41-r5.

Comment: Worked for me but after it launched seems crashed slow mouse movements

Comment: This worked for me too, but having an explanation of *why* it works would be great.

Answer (score 29):

I managed to solved my problem :

I just changed the display option Graphics Controller to VBoxVGA and enabled 3D Acceleration.

Comment: This does the job! But FYI, your second recommendation of 3d animation is [the official recommendation](http://www.android-x86.org/documents/virtualboxhowto) anyway. I wish their manual will be updated with your first recommendation though!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the tweaks to do with VirtualBox. It works smoothly now.

Comment: It works like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: That, however, would seem to be a problem in the future, as VBoxVGA is deprecated. VBoxSVGA appears to work.

Comment: Isn't "3D animation" supposed to be "3D Acceleration"?

Comment: I have black screen. what should I do?

Comment: Won't work, you can't use 3d acceleration with VBoxVGA

Comment: @Valentin How did you do that exactly?

Comment: In display settings, you can find Graphics Controller and 3D acceleration

Comment: With both options on, VBOX would complain. I had to turn off 3D accel.