# Don't boot in Android GUI, just in command line

Tags: linux, android-x86

I have the same issue as in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1395714/dont-boot-in-gui-but-just-in-command-line?newreg=8086ebc33a1145f689f288864908172c) but I want to know what I have to do in a real machine to solve it. I want to load Android x86 GUI normaly but this load into command line.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Android-x86 has problems with your graphic card. I had this issue in the past and managed to fix it but it was two years ago, so I didn't remember the precise steps. But the following links will help you for sure.

### Quick fix

Edit the boot command by typing `e` or `TAB` and replace `quiet` by `nomodeset xforcevesa`

The parameter "nomodeset" disables "the kernel mode setting" (tells the kernel to not set the graphic resolution, let X do that instead) and "xforcevesa" enforces to use the VESA driver for X.

See [here](https://www.android-x86.org/documentation/graphic_card.html) for more details.

### Permanent fix

It seems you can permanently edit the boot command by following these [steps](https://androidadepth.blogspot.com/2019/04/android-x86-virtual-machine.html).