# VirtualBox will not allow me to select VBoxVGA or VBoxSVGA with 3D acceleration selected when setting up Android x86

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, android-x86

I'm trying to get Android x86 running in VirtualBox, to test it out as a viable replacement for my RPi 3B running OSMC, because I want something that I can install Netflix and other on demand TV services. I live in the UK so some of the programmes that I want to watch just have no availability and the Kodi addons that are available for UK TV shows just aren't up to scratch; also, I don't trust any 3rd party addon that I have to put a username and password in for legit services like Netflix.

The problem I am having is that in VirtualBox the default display settings uses VMSVGA and Android x86 just doesn't boot into the GUI, it just hangs on  "A N D R O I D android_x86:/ #"

The solutions that seem to work are changing the display mode to VBoxVGA or VBoxSVGA; however, if I select 3D Accelertation it reverts back to VMSVGA. But if I don't select 3D acceleration it will eventually boot into the GUI, but it's sluggish and barely useable.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

My VirtualBox version is  6.1.4 r136177 and I am running Windows 10 Pro N 2004 build 19041.450 and Android x86 is cm-14.1-x86

Answer (score 2):

Virtualbox 6.1 removes the support for VboxVGA 3D acceleration (also VboxSVGA). Its old and probably will be removed in future releases. Prefer using 6.0 or 5.2 version. Though those are outdated, but your vm will work fine.

> This VM is configured to use 3D acceleration using the VBoxVGA graphics controller. Support for this will be removed with version 6.1.0. ALL saved states and snapshots will cease to work when using this configuration. Either switch to the VBoxSVGA (or VMSVGA) graphics controller and update guest additions, or disable 3D acceleration."

Source: [Upgraded my VB 2 v6.0.12, but XP guest VM warns me about its 3D acceleration support being removed.](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=94564)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of editing Virtual Box configurations to match with Android x86 default graphical card settings, you can edit Android x86 graphical card settings to match the one of Virtual Box.

See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1512632/dont-boot-in-android-gui-just-in-command-line).